# How to re-prompt user input after incorrect type of data is given and also re prompt user input if they want to?

Tags: python-3.6

The program is about finding factors and if the user enters a special character or an alphabet it will show an error and I wanted to ask the user to try again "Invalid input please try again" after the error shows and also after the program shows the factors I wanted the user to have the chance to find another factor again "Try again? Yes/No"

I've tried the 
while True:
    if input("Try Again? (Yes/No)").strip().upper() == 'No':
     break
but i don't know how to make it work.
Any other solutions will do

```
def print_factors(x):
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):    
        if x % i == 0:
            print(i)


try:  
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print_factors(num)

except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.");
```

The program works and I just wanted to put some add ons

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter an integer (0 to exit): "))
        if num == 0:
           break
        print(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, you must enter an integer")
```

Comment: it works awesome 
but it only ask the user twice and stops
how do i make it loop forever if the user wants
how do i prompt the user to find another integer if he wants or not 
"try again? yes/no"

Comment: You're right. Hang on I'll update it. We need a way to terminate it, so how about entering 0 (you could use -1, or anything else you like)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UPM5hR7 

I tried it out here's the results

how do i make the negatives stop making an error in my program

Comment: In the above, negative numbers work fine and print the same negative number out, just like in the link you provided. If you are asking about your factoring routine, then the factors of a negative number are the same as the factors of the positive number, plus the negative of those factors. Like factors of -9 are 1, -1, 3, -3, 9, -9. It is probably easiest to treat this is a special case by factoring it as a positive number and printing out the negative factor as well.